# I'm facing issue with my Authority pro Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, blogs

Madam.

I am using **Authority Pro Theme** as a child theme and **Genesis** as a Parent theme for my blogging on Wordpress.

I'm facing Two Issue.

**1.)** I have updated a **Hero image** in my landing page but when I visit website after saving it, the image showing is still a previous one, Means whenever I try to update a new image it doesn't updated.

See the attached SS of my HomePage in both scenario while I'm Loggedin on Wordpress and without loggin in.

[With Log in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE6nl.png)
[Without Log in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRr8g.png)

**2.)** Second issue that I'm facing is in the Category section. Whenever I'm publishing any blog under any category it was also visible in homepage also but this time it is not showing, don't know why, but it is visible when we visit to that particular category, but as a theme default setting the post should also visible in the homepage, see the below image for a better understanding of what I'm trying to say.

[This is a homepage and **Education** is category and every latest post with this category shows up here, but my latest post about **Cryptocurrency** is not showing up here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VajVE.png)

Your Help would be so appreciated, please if you can answer this question please have a look at my question once.

Thank You So Much.

I tries clearing cache from Wordpress Dashboard, From Hostinger H panel, From CLoudflare as well, and also waited several week, but the issue still persist.